# Type signatures for this passed to free-standing functions

Tags: types, typescript, method-signature

Here is the code:

```
interface Foo
{
    c : string
}

function foo()
{
    var c = this.c
    return c
}

foo.call({ c : "quux" })
```

Visual Studio says that `this : any` so autocompletion of `this.c` doesn't work. How do I add a signature to tell that `this` implements `Foo` so IDE has type info for autocompletion of `this.` inside `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply create a temp variable:

```
var self:Foo = this;
var c = self.c
return c
```

There is an open issue to specify what `this` means in an arbitrary context that you can vote/contribute to : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/507

Answer (score 0):

Since the function `foo` could be used with any `this` context, you'd need to use a type assertion:

```
var c = (<Foo>this).c;
```

Otherwise, the signature can't be inferred.